# Can't find <tr> data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access rows of the table from `https://www.parliament.gov.za/hansard?sorts[date]=-1`. I ultimately want to download the PDFs contained in each row, but I am having a hard time accessing the rows of the table. When I inspect a table row element, I see that it is under the `<tbody>` tag. However, I can't seem to access this data using BeautifulSoup. I have done a decent amount of web scraping, but this is the first time I've run into this issue. This is the code that I currently have:

```
import requests
from bs4
import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.parliament.gov.za/hansard?sorts[date]=-1'

request = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(request.text, 'html.parser')

table1 = soup.findAll('table')[0]

print(table1)
```

**Output:**

```html
<table id="papers-table">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>House</th>
    <th>Language</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th data-dynatable-column="file_location" style="display:none">File Location</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Clearly, there is nothing in the `<tbody>` tag even though this is where I believe the row data should be. In general, whenever I try to find the tr tags, which is where Chrome says the row data is stored, I can't find any of the ones with the PDFs. I am fairly certain that the issue has something to do with the fact that the source code is missing this data as well, but I have no idea how to find it. Since it's on the website, I assume that there must be a way, right? Thanks!

Comment: The table is loaded using JavaScript, if you go to the parliament page then right click and select view page source, you will see the table itself is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` won't support it. However, the data is available via sending a `GET` request to the websites API:

```
https://www.parliament.gov.za/docsjson?queries%5Btype%5D=hansard&sorts%5Bdate%5D=-1&page=1&perPage=10&offset=0
```

There's no need to use `BeautifuSoup`, using just the `requests` library is enough:

```
import requests


URL = "https://www.parliament.gov.za/docsjson?queries%5Btype%5D=hansard&sorts%5Bdate%5D=-1&page=1&perPage=10&offset=0"
BASE_URL = "https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/"
response = requests.get(URL).json()

for data in response["records"]:
    print(BASE_URL + data["file_location"])
```

Output:

```
https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/hansard/3a888bc6-ffc7-46a1-9803-ffc148b07bfc.pdf
https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/hansard/3eb3103c-2d3c-418f-bb24-494b17bdeb22.pdf
https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/hansard/bf0afdf8-352c-4dde-a380-11ce0a038dad.pdf
https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/hansard/285e1633-aaeb-4a0d-bd54-98a4d5ec5127.pdf
https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/hansard/966926ce-4cfe-4f68-b4a1-f99a09433137.pdf
https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/hansard/d4bdb2c2-e8c8-461f-bc0b-9ffff3403be3.pdf
https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/hansard/daecc145-bb44-47f1-a3b2-9400437f71d8.pdf
https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/hansard/4f204d7e-0a25-4b64-b5a7-46c8730abe91.pdf
https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/hansard/f2863e16-b448-46e3-939d-e14859984513.pdf
https://www.parliament.gov.za/storage/app/media/Docs/hansard/cd30e289-2ff2-47f5-b2a7-77e496e52f3a.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, could you explain where you got the value assigned to URL from? This might be a dumb question, but it's not the original link so I don't know what it is.

Comment: @Grant In your browser open your "Developer Tools" (usually the F12 key) select "Network" and monitor the traffic calls

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to scrape dynamic content whereas you're only loading the html for a static page with requests. Look for ways to get the dynamically generated html code or use selenium.